# My ethers didn't show up

Tags: mist, ether, bitcoin, mac-osx, shapeshift

Yesterday I have installed the Ethereum-Wallet on my Mac.

When it was installing, a popup showed up to exchange some bitcoins into ethers using an app called `Shifty`.

I made the transfer, and the bitcoin transaction [was confirmed](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/27df4485ee6f470b69d638e6d678b1e7e509b33fa7877cbaf30728570fc2f464).

Even after the bitcoin transaction confirmation, the ethers doesn't showed up in my wallet. Reading about that on the internet, I saw that some people had this problem, and they only need to wait the full sync to the wallet be updated with the correct information.

Today my sync is complete, and I don't have the ethers yet.
Worse than that: when I inspect my address on etherchain, it says that [address is not found](https://www.etherchain.org/account/0x0bCC7415a664130e483F1a6bbeDCbD5e28C8d496)

Anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Ethereum Wallet only has the ability to handle Ethereum accounts. You would have to use an exchange like ShapeShift to convert your bitcoins into ethers. Please provide more details on the steps you have performed. If you have your Ethereum address, you can plug this address into https://etherchain.org/ to check the balance.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah I updated the question with more details... Tks :)

Comment: I see. You have used the "Deposit using Bitcoin" functionality that sends your bitcoins to https://shapeshift.io/ for conversion into ethers. Did you specify a "Return Address" or "Email for Receipt"? I can see that there was a confirmed bitcoin transaction from your link. I have not used ShapeShift but from what I have read, they will help you chase up your problematic transactions. They have a support page at  https://shapeshift.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new where you can enter your transaction ids and deposit address.

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: I have contacted the shapeshift.io support and they refunded my bitcoins :)